# Calculate frequency for each age group in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have an input data which looks like as shown below

```
Person_id   Age
21352471    59
22157363    51
22741394    75
22764902    27
22771872    62
```

I am trying to calculate the frequency (no of patients) under each age group like `0-10`, `11-20`, `21-30` etc

Can help me as to how it can be done?

I was trying something like below by referring online but this doesn't help

```
select
  person_id,
  count(*) filter (where age<=10) as "0-10",
  count(*) filter (where age>10 and age<=20) as "11-20",
  count(*) filter (where age>20) as "21-30"
from
  age_table
group by
  person_id;
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
Age_group  freq
0-10         0
11-20        0
21-30        1
31-40        0
41-50        0
51-60        2
61-70        1
71-80        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select case when age<=10 then "0-10"
when age>10 and age<=20 then "11-20"
when age>20 and age<=30 then "21-30" end as age_group
count(person_id) as freq
from
  age_table
group by
case when age<=10 then "0-10"
when age>10 and age<=20 then "11-20"
when age>20 and age<=30 then "21-30" end
```

Comment: @TheGreat . . . Postgres allows you to repeat the column alias in the `group by`, which is a bit simplification.

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to do this which splits the ages into batches of 10 as follows

```
select concat(
        (age/10)*10 
       ,'-'
       ,(age/10)*10+10
        )as age_bracket
      ,count(person_id) as frequency
 from t
group by concat(
        (age/10)*10 
       ,'-'
       ,(age/10)*10+10
        )
order by 1  


+-------------+-----------+
| age_bracket | frequency |
+-------------+-----------+
| 20-30       |         1 |
| 50-60       |         2 |
| 60-70       |         1 |
| 70-80       |         1 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

dbfiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=720d56ae4428a3ddd25ecb5bdac3b7fa

Comment: PostgreSQL supports `group by 1`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=494c0402fdbdf804a548c264f1cc3d49

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer if you are keen to show up all the age ranges from 0-100 regardless of if there were entries or not

```
with data
  as (select concat(
                   case when x=1 then 0 else (x-1)*10+1 end
                   ,'-'
                   ,x*10
                  ) as ranges
             ,case when x=1 then 0 else (x-1)*10+1 end lv
             ,x*10 as hv
        from generate_series(1,10) x
      ) 
    select d.ranges as age_bracket
          ,count(t.person_id) as frequency
     from data d
left join t 
       on t.age>=d.lv
      and t.age<=d.hv
group by d.ranges 
order by 1

-------------+-----------+
| age_bracket | frequency |
+-------------+-----------+
| 0-10        |         0 |
| 11-20       |         0 |
| 21-30       |         1 |
| 31-40       |         0 |
| 41-50       |         0 |
| 51-60       |         2 |
| 61-70       |         1 |
| 71-80       |         1 |
| 81-90       |         0 |
| 91-100      |         0 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

db fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d21a1ef85d017a3d891ec6f85269a381